# How do I determine whether $18 \notin A$ with these premises?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

With $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, given that

> A1. $(x \in A \land y \in A) \implies x^2 + y ^2 \in A$
>
> A2. $1 \in A$
>
> A3. $3 \notin A$

Determine whether:

> $18 \notin A$

I've been unable to prove this. First, I tried to demonstrate $18 \in A$, but no matter what I try, I can't land in $18$, so I guess that $18 \notin A$ should be true - but how can I prove it? I have never used $3 \notin A$, which is probably the key, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: How many integer pairs $x,y$ exist such that $x^2+y^2=18$?

Comment: @abiessu: I don't see why we could assume that $18=x^2+y^2$ with integers $x,y$. A2 only says, that $x^2+y^2\in A$, **if** one of $x,y$ was already in $A$.

Comment: @abiessu: Well, I don't know how many, but I do know that $3$ and $3$ fulfills it. If that's the only pair, and $3 \notin A$, I suppose that $18 \notin A$ is... false. But now then, I'm not sure if they're the only pair.

Comment: Surely I'm mistaken, but the set $A = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{3\}$ fits the requirements. And it contains 18.

Comment: @nik Both $\mathbb N \backslash \{3 \}$ and $\mathbb N \backslash \{ 3, 18 \}$ fit the requirements.

Comment: @N.S.: So you can't prove that $18 \not\in A$ only from these axioms.

Comment: What does A1 mean if there is no quantifier for x and y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** (1) Give an example of a set $A$ that satisfies the conditions and such that $18\in A$.

(2) Give an example of a set $A$ that satisfies the conditions but such that $18\not\in A$.

These two examples will show that (1) from the assumptions, we cannot prove that $18\not\in A$ and (2) from the assumptions we cannot prove that $18\in A$.

Comment: I'm not certain how you can claim that $18\in A$ is an uncertain proposition, given the claims on $A$.  Can you demonstrate a set matching your condition $(1)$?  PS  I thought your hint was a good start for the OP, and I was surprised you got a downvote for it previously...

Comment: @abiessu $\mathbb N \backslash \{ 3 \}$... And $\mathbb N \backslash \{3, 18 \}$ works for $(2)$ ;)

Comment: @N.S.: it took me a while to see and then actually admit it, but you are right...

Comment: As has been pointed out already, for (1) take everything but $3$. Closure under $x^2+y^2$ is clear. A very similar example works for (2).

Comment: I'm having problems with (1): the only way to have $18 \in A$ is by $3 \in A$, but the third axiom says that $3 \notin A$. As for (2): Well, $\{ 1 \}$ would work fine, right? Because it doesn't have $18$.

Comment: @Omega why? Unless $A$ is defined to be the minimal set with those properties, $18$ can be in $A$ without $3$ being. Note that $A1$ is just an implication, doesn't mean the converse is also true.

Comment: @Omega To put it simple, set $A= \mathbb N \backslash \{ 3\}$. Does this set satisfy $A1), A2)$ and $A3$?

Comment: On (1), the axiom says that **if**  $x$ and $y$ are in $A$, **then** $x^2+y^2\in A$. It does not say **if and only if**. For (2), we are **forced** to put in $2$, $5$, $8$, and many others. The point is that we are not forced to put in $18$. The example suggested by N.S. (everybody but $3$ and $18$) is closed under the operation $x^2+y^2$, so it satisfies axioms A1 to A3.

Comment: @N.S.: Ah! An implication... you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\phantom{\left(1 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 1 \in A\right)} 
&\phantom{\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1^{2} + 1^{2} =} 1 \in A 
\\
\left(1 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 1 \in A\right) 
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1^{2} + 1^{2} = 2 \in A 
\\
\phantom{\left(1 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 1 \in A\right)} 
&\phantom{\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1^{2} + 1^{2} =} \color{#ff0000}{\,3 \not\in A} 
\\
\left(1 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 2 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1^{2} + 2^{2} = 5 \in A 
\\
\left(2 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 2 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
2^{2} + 2^{2} = 8 \in A 
\\
\left(1 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 3 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1^{2} + 3^{2} = 10 \in A 
\\
\left(2 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 3 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
2^{2} + 3^{2} = 13 \in A 
\\
\left(1 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 4 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1^{2} + 4^{2} = 17 \in A 
\\
\left(4 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 2 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
4^{2} + 2^{2} = 20 \in A 
\\
\left(1 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 5 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1^{2} + 5^{2} = 26 \in A 
\\
\left(2 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 5 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
2^{2} + 5^{2} = 29 \in A 
\\
\left(1 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 6 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
1^{2} + 6^{2} = 37 \in A 
\\
\left(2 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 6 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
2^{2} + 6^{2} = 40 \in A 
\\
\left(4 \in A\quad \wedge\quad 5 \in A\right)
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
4^{2} + 5^{2} = 41 \in A 
\\&\vdots
\\[5mm]&
\end{align}

$$
\left\{%
1,2,5,8,10,13,17,20,26,29,37,40,41...
\right\}
$$

Comment: It would help if you could add how you arrived at this answer. Regards

Comment: So basically you tried every possible combination ((1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(1,5),...) up to some extent and verified that $18$ is not in the result? While I think this is a nice idea, is this enough for a formal demonstration?